# When defined in a script, Julia functions don't print output

Tags: julia

I have this Julia script:

```
function f(x,y)
    x+y
end

f(3, 4)
```

When I run this in the live terminal (via copy/paste), I get the desired result 7. But if I run the script, the output from the function is suppressed. Why is that?

Comment: How do you "run the script"? I would assume that you explicitly have to `print` something if you want to display outputs outside of Julia?

Comment: I run the script by executing it either from a terminal of my choice via "/path/to/julia myScript.jl" or from the Julia terminal via "include("path/to/myScript.jl")". The result is the same in both cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Julia, unlike Matlab, doesn't automatically print values (the REPL does since that's what it's for: REPL = "read, eval, print loop"). You have to explicitly print the value using `print` or `show`, e.g. `show(f(3, 4))`. In this case, `print` and `show` do the same thing, but in general they have somewhat different meanings:

> `print([io::IO], xs...)`
>
> Write to io (or to the default output stream stdout if io is not given) a canonical (un-decorated) text representation. The representation used by print includes minimal formatting and tries to avoid Julia-specific details.

versus

> `show(x)`
>
> Write an informative text representation of a value to the current output stream. New types should overload show(io::IO, x) where the first argument is a stream. The representation used by show generally includes Julia-specific formatting and type information.

Note that there is also the `@show` macro, which prints the expression that is evaluated followed by its value, like so:

```
julia> @show f(3, 4);
f(3, 4) = 7
```

Comment: So being able to choose between suppressing or displaying the output by adding semicolon is a feature specific to the REPL then? Is there no equivalent for scripts?

Comment: It's not like in Matlab. Nothing is printed in a script, unless you call a printing function. An in the REPL, you have one expression per line, the result of which is printed. (And the result of `something;` is `nothing`.)

Comment: Yes, semicolon print suppression is only in the REPL. Alternatively, you can bring of `something;` as being shorthand for `something; nothing` which evaluates to `nothing`.